# Place the contents of a cell into an Excel sheet header or footer when the cell contents change

Tags: excel, header, footer

I'm using Excel 365 in Windows and I'm trying to have the contents of certain cells copied to the sheet header (or footer) when the cell contents change. For example, I'm creating a series of data sheets and on page one I have a cell where the user types in the purchase order (PO) used by the customer. I would like to have the user enter the PO number once and then have the PO number placed in all subsequent footers. When the stack of data sheets is printed the PO (and other key info) will be on all pages.
I know that Excel does not do this naturally and I've found some rather ugly macro and VB code to do this programatically via Google but I had trouble making it work. so....I'm hoping for some simpler magic.

```
Private HeaderSave() As Variant
Private HeaderChanged() As Variant

Public Sub SaveAndSetHeaders()

Dim Index As Long

' Save and set header and footer text Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ReDim HeaderSave(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) ReDim HeaderChanged(1 To 
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count, 0 To 5)'

For Index = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup
      HeaderSave(Index) = Array(.LeftHeader, .CenterHeader, .RightHeader, 
      .LeftFooter, .CenterFooter, .RightFooter)

   If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(0), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .LeftHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index),
        HeaderSave(Index)(0))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 0) = True
   End If

   If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(1), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .CenterHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), 
        HeaderSave(Index)(1))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 1) = True
   End If

   If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(2), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .RightHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), 
         HeaderSave(Index)(2))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 2) = True
   End If

  If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(3), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .LeftFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), 
        HeaderSave(Index)(3))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 3) = True
  End If

  If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(4), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .CenterFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), 
        HeaderSave(Index)(4))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 4) = True
  End If

  If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(5), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
        .RightFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), 
        HeaderSave(Index)(5))
        HeaderChanged(Index, 5) = True
 End If
End With

Next Index
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Sub RestoreHeaders()

Dim Index As Long

   ' Restore header and footer text'

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Index = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 0) Then .LeftHeader = HeaderSave(Index)(0)
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 1) Then .CenterHeader = HeaderSave(Index)(1)
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 2) Then .RightHeader = HeaderSave(Index)(2)
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 3) Then .LeftFooter = HeaderSave(Index)(3)
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 4) Then .CenterFooter = HeaderSave(Index)(4)
      If HeaderChanged(Index, 5) Then .RightFooter = HeaderSave(Index)(5)
  End With
 Next Index

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function SubstituteCellValues( _
    ByVal FocusSheet As Worksheet, _
    ByVal Text As String _
    ) As String

' Look for the text "^[Cell:A1]" and replace it with the cell's value. The 
  cell reference can be any valid cell reference with or without a sheet 
  name. If no sheet name is included the sheet for which the header or 
  footer text is defined is assumed.'

Dim StartPos As Long
Dim EndPos As Long
Dim FindText As String
Dim ReplaceText As String
Dim CellReference As String

Do
  StartPos = InStr(Text, "^[Cell:")

  If StartPos > 0 Then
     EndPos = InStr(StartPos, Text, "]") 
         If EndPos = 0 Then Exit Do
             FindText = Mid(Text, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1)
             CellReference = Mid(FindText, 8, Len(FindText) - 8)
         If InStr(CellReference, "!") = 0 Then
             CellReference = "'" & FocusSheet.Name & "'!" & CellReference
         End If
     On Error Resume Next
     ReplaceText = Range(CellReference).Value
     On Error GoTo 0
     Text = Replace(Text, FindText, ReplaceText)
  Else
     Exit Do
  End If
Loop

SubstituteCellValues = Text

End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
   SaveAndSetHeaders
   Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.Workbook_AfterPrint"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterPrint() 
   RestoreHeaders
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51884605/edit) your question and add the code you do have? It will make it easier to see if what we have in mind is indeed simpler than what you already have.

Comment: The code below was snipped form a blogger named Zorvek who was addressing this problem. Ugh...made some bad mouse clicks and I've scrambled my reply. The code snippet should post above.

Comment: don't add the info in comments [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51884605/edit) your question instead